# How to upload a folder to Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to upload an entire folder to azure storage.
I know I can upload a file using:

```
blobReference.UploadFromFile(fileName);
```

But could not find a method to upload an entire folder (recursively).
Is there such method? Or maybe an example code?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so there is such method, since there is a flat hierarchy on azure with everything being a blob within a container. You would have to iterate through each file and upload it.

Comment: That isn't true, Azure supports subfolders in blob containers.

Comment: `Azure supports subfolders in blob containers` - Not true. A subfolder is simply a prefix to a blob's name. You can't create an empty subfolder in Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: A quick google yields this: http://www.dotnetspeak.com/azure/uploading-directory-to-azure-blob-storage/

Comment: Splitting hairs Gaurav, Azure has enough support for prefixes that they are in effect subfolders. Their own explorer tool shows them as such.

Comment: Just by using the Azure Storage explorer, I can copy a folder into a container, so I know it supports this. I would like to do it in code (c#)

Comment: @Simon - not splitting hairs at all. There are *no subfolders*. Just try enumerating content in a container with 100,000 items, with a few of them in a "subfolder" (which isn't a subfolder). You'll still enumerate all 100,000 items while searching for the right items (because it has to search for prefix name). Also FYI Gaurav wrote one of the very first (and very popular) Azure storage explorer tools - he knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The folder structure can simply be part of the filename:

```
string myfolder = "datadir";
string myfilename = "mydatafile";
string fileName = String.Format("{0}/{1}.csv", myfolder, myfilename);
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
```

If you upload like this example, files would appear in the container in the 'datadir' folder.

That means that you can use this to copy a directory structure to upload:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
    // file would look like "C:\dir1\dir2\blah.txt"

    // Don't know if this is the prettiest way, but it will work:
    string cloudfilename = file.Substring(3).Replace('\\', '/');

    // get the blob reference and push the file contents to it:
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(cloudfileName);
    blob.UploadFromFile(file);
  }
```

Comment: Any idea how to do to the opposite? Downloading a folder from the storage...?

Answer (score 1):

The command line does not have an option to bulk upload multiple files in one invocation. However, you can either use find or a loop to upload multiple files like this for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT='your_account'
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY='your_access_key'

export container_name='name_of_the_container_to_create'
export source_folder=~/path_to_local_file_to_upload/*


echo "Creating the container..."
azure storage container create $container_name

for f in $source_folder
do
  echo "Uploading $f file..."
  azure storage blob upload $f $container_name $(basename $f)
  cat $f
done

echo "Listing the blobs..."
azure storage blob list $container_name

echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Microsoft Azure Storage DataMovement Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/) which support transferring blob directory with high-performance, scalability and reliability. In addition, it supports cancelling and then resuming during transferring. [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples/Samples.cs#L264) is a sample of uploading a folder to Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 1):

From the CLI you can use:

```
az storage blob upload-batch
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch